# Understanding the speed up of openmp program across NUMA nodes

Tags: openmp, hpc, numa

I came across this behavior of speed up and I am finding it hard to explain. Following is the background:

1. Program

Invocation of Gaussian Elimination method to solve linear equation within a loop to parallelize the work load across compute units. We use an augmented matrix of dimension (M by M+1) where one additional column holds the RHS

2. HPC Setup - Cray XC50 node with Intel Xeon 6148 Gold with the following configuration

```
available: 2 nodes (0-1)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
node 0 size: 95325 MB
node 0 free: 93811 MB
node 1 cpus: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
node 1 size: 96760 MB
node 1 free: 96374 MB
node distances:
node   0   1
  0:  10  21
  1:  21  10
```

Although not the actual HPC, but the block diagram and the related explanation seems to fully apply (https://www.nas.nasa.gov/hecc/support/kb/skylake-processors_550.html). Specifically sub NUMA clustering seems to be disabled.

3. Job submitted through APLS is as follows

```
time aprun -n 1 -d 20 -j 1 -ss -cc 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 -e N=4000 -e M=200 -e MODE=2 ./gem
time aprun -n 1 -d 20 -j 1 -ss -cc 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29 -e N=4000 -e M=200 -e MODE=2 ./gem
time aprun -n 1 -d 20 -j 1 -ss -cc 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29 -e N=4000 -e M=200 -e MODE=2 ./gem
time aprun -n 1 -d 20 -j 1 -ss -cc 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39 -e N=4000 -e M=200 -e MODE=2 ./gem
time aprun -n 1 -d 20 -j 1 -ss -cc 40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69 -e N=4000 -e M=200 -e MODE=2 ./gem
```

In the above N indicates the number of matrices and M replaces the dimension of the matrix. These are passed as environment variable to the program and used internally. MODE can be ignored for this discussion
cc list specifically lists the CPUs to bind with. OMP_NUM_THREADS is set to 20. The intent is to use 20 threads across 20 compute units.

4. Time to run sequentially and parallel is recorded within the program using omp_get_wtime() and the results are the following

| CPU Binding | Objective | Speed Up |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 | Load work across 20 physical cores on socket 0 | 13.081944 |
| 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29 | Spread across first 10 physical cores on socket 0 & socket 1 | 18.332559 |
| 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29 | Spread across 2nd set of 1o physical cores on socket 0 & first 10 of socket 1 | 18.636265 |
| 40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69 | Spread across virtual cores across sockets(40-0, 60-21) | 15.922209 |

Why is the speed up less for the first case when all physical nodes on socket 0 are being used ? The understanding here is that when tasks are spread across sockets, UPI comes into effect and it should be slower whereas it seems to be exactly the opposite. Also what can possibly explain the last scenario when virtual cores are being used.

Note: We have tried multiple iterations and the results for the above combinations are pretty consistent.

Edit1: [image: Output of lstopo]

Edit2: Source code

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sched.h"
#include "omp.h"

double drand(double low, double high, unsigned int *seed)
{
    return ((double)rand_r(seed) * (high - low)) / (double)RAND_MAX + low;
}

void init_vars(int *N, int *M, int *mode)
{
    const char *number_of_instances = getenv("N");
    if (number_of_instances) {
        *N = atoi(number_of_instances);
    }

    const char *matrix_dim = getenv("M");
    if (matrix_dim) {
        *M = atoi(matrix_dim);
    }

    const char *running_mode = getenv("MODE");
    if (running_mode) {
        *mode = atoi(running_mode);
    }
}

void print_matrix(double *instance, int M)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < M; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column <= M; column++) {
            printf("%lf ", instance[row * (M + 1) + column]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void swap(double *a, double *b)
{
    double temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void init_matrix(double *instance, unsigned int M)
{
    unsigned int seed = 45613 + 19 * omp_get_thread_num();
    for (int row = 0; row < M; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column <= M; column++) {
            instance[row * (M + 1) + column] = drand(-1.0, 1.0, &seed);
        }
    }
}

void initialize_and_solve(int M)
{
    double *instance;
    instance = malloc(M * (M + 1) * sizeof(double));

    // Initialise the matrix
    init_matrix(instance, M);

    // Performing elementary operations
    int i, j, k = 0, c, flag = 0, m = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        if (instance[i * (M + 2)] == 0) {
            c = 1;
            while ((i + c) < M && instance[(i + c) * (M + 1) + i] == 0)
                c++;

            if ((i + c) == M) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }

            for (j = i, k = 0; k <= M; k++) {
                swap(&instance[j * (M + 1) + k], &instance[(j + c) * (M + 1) + k]);
            }
        }

        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            // Excluding all i == j
            if (i != j) {
                // Converting Matrix to reduced row
                // echelon form(diagonal matrix)
                double pro = instance[j * (M + 1) + i] / instance[i * (M + 2)];

                for (k = 0; k <= M; k++)
                    instance[j * (M + 1) + k] -= (instance[i * (M + 1) + k]) * pro;
            }
        }
    }

    // Get the solution in the last column
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        instance[i * (M + 1) + M] /= instance[i * (M + 2)];
    }

    free(instance);
    instance = NULL;
}

double solve_serial(int N, int M)
{
    double now = omp_get_wtime();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        initialize_and_solve(M);
    }
    return omp_get_wtime() - now;
}

double solve_parallel(int N, int M)
{
    double now = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        initialize_and_solve(M);
    }
    return omp_get_wtime() - now;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Default parameters
    int N = 200, M = 200, mode = 2;

    if (argc == 4) {
        N = atoi(argv[1]);
        M = atoi(argv[2]);
        mode = atoi(argv[3]);
    }

    init_vars(&N, &M, &mode);

    if (mode == 0) {
        // Serial only
        double l2_norm_serial = 0.0;
        double serial = solve_serial(N, M);
        printf("Time, %d, %d, %lf\n", N, M, serial);
    } else if (mode == 1) {
        // Parallel only
        double l2_norm_parallel = 0.0;
        double parallel = solve_parallel(N, M);
        printf("Time, %d, %d, %lf\n", N, M, parallel);
    } else {
        // Both serial and parallel
        // Solve using GEM (serial)
        double serial = solve_serial(N, M);

        // Solve using GEM (parallel)
        double parallel = solve_parallel(N, M);

        printf("Time, %d, %d, %lf, %lf, %lf\n", N, M, serial, parallel, serial / parallel);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit3: Rephrased the first point to clarify what is actually being done ( based on feedback in comment )

Comment: Your code is 100 percent wrong. You're not solving a Gaussian elimination in parallel: you're doing a bunch of separate GE calls. This is pointless. This is the loop that you need to make parallel: `for (j = 0; j < M; j++)`

Comment: We are not trying to parallelize Gaussian Elimination. Please take a look at the solve_parallel method. The intent is to parallelize the loop such that all compute units are loaded such that we get nearly 20x speed up

Comment: 20x speed up over what? You're doing the same operation 20 times. what's the point in that?

Comment: (Near) 20x speed up using 20 cores. Please note that the intent is to verify that we are able to utilize all the compute units efficiently using openmp primitive.

Comment: What's the point in doing 20 identical operations?

Comment: Also, you're timing the `malloc` call and the random number generator so whatever you're measuring might well be meaningless.

Comment: Point is to verify the speed up from HPC. We have tried with 1) malloc+init being done in main thread; 2) malloc+init being done in another parallel construct using omp parallel before calling solve_parallel. There is no significant difference in behavior. This is the 3rd case wherein we are doing malloc within the openmp threads

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the speed up less for the first case when all physical nodes on socket 0 are being used ?

Results are often dependent of the application but some patterns regularly happens. My guess is that your application heavily use the main RAM and **2 sockets results in more DDR4 RAM blocks being used** than only one. Indeed, with local NUMA-node allocations, 1 socket can access to the RAM at the speed of 128 GB/s while 2 sockets can access to the RAM at the speed of 256 GB/s. With a balanced use of DDR4 RAM blocks, the performance with be far worst and bounded by UPI (I do not expect 2 socket to be much slower because of the full-duplex data transfer).

> The understanding here is that when tasks are spread across sockets, UPI comes into effect and it should be slower whereas it seems to be exactly the opposite.

UPI is only a bottleneck if data are massively transferred between the two sockets, but good NUMA applications should not do that because they should operate on their own NUMA-node memory.

You can check the use of the UPI and RAM throughput using **hardware counters**.

> Also what can possibly explain the last scenario when virtual cores are being used.

I do not have an explanation for this. Note higher IDs are the second hyperthreads of each core so it is certainly related to a low-level behaviour of the hyperthreading (maybe some processes are bound to some PU causing pre-emption the target PUs or simply the second PU have somehow a lower priority). Note also that physical core IDs and logical PU IDs are often not mapped the same way so if you use the wrong one you could end up binding 2 threads to the same core. I advise you to use **hwloc** to check that.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question and added the output of lstopo command

Comment: Also included the source code in place within the question.

Comment: I confirm the answer based on the provided information. I still do not know for the last case. It is certainly due to a low-level CPU behaviour or some process mapped. This is quite weird. Hardware profiling can help to understand what is going on. `hwloc-ps` on the target machine can be used to check the actual mapping (this is interesting in case of OS mapping bugs which are quite rare but can happen).

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me try the hwloc-ps. To corroborate the finding, let me once again try doing a single malloc() such that entire memory is allocated on node 0 and see how the speed up changes. I think the expectation is that speed up should decrease!

Comment: "*a single malloc() such that entire memory is allocated on node 0*" By default, Linux does not map the page at allocation time but during the first touch so the location of the malloc call does not matter much. What actually matters is where the *first touch* is done (unless the default allocation policy has been changed). In your case this is fine because `initialize_and_solve` is done in a parallel for. Binding each thread to a specific PU may help (using manual places in `OMP_PLACES` and using `OMP_PROC_BIND=true`).

Answer (score 0):

You say you implement a "Simple implementation of Gaussian Elimination". Sorry, there is no such thing. There are multiple different algorithms and they all come with their own analysis. But let's assume you use the textbook one. Even then, Gaussian Elimination is not simple.

First of all, you haven't stated that you initialized your data in parallel. If you don't do that, all the data will wind up on socket 0 and you will get bad performance, never mind the speedup. But let's assume you did the right thing here. (If not, google "first touch".)

In the GE algorithm, each of the sequential `k` iterations works on a smaller and smaller subset of the data. This means that no simple mapping of data to cores is possible. If you place your data in such a way that initially each core works on local data, this will quickly no longer be the case.

In fact, after half the number of iterations, half your cores will be pulling data from the other socket, leading to NUMA coherence delays. Maybe a `spread` binding is better here than your `compact` binding.

Comment: Apologies for missing out mentioning about the data initialization. We have earlier tried with parallel initialization of data and there was no significant difference in behavior. The data captured above is for the case when each matrix is being initialized locally from the openmp spawned thread using malloc

Comment: Also would like to add that when 10 cores are engaged(independent of the set used), we consistently get a Speed Up of 9.3 to 9.4x inline with expectations.

Comment: Hello. I have also included the source code inline within the question as well as the output of lstopo